# DAC connection to sql instance not working

Tags: dac

I have configured one remote sql server with 2 instances A,B. I have enabled TCP/IP,Port 1434, remote connections, sql browser running and firewall inbound rule. I've enable DAC using sp_configure 'remote admin connections', 1; and reconfigure. However when I try to connect via SSMS or SQLCMD using admin:hostmachine\sqlinstance or sqlcmd -S hostmachine\sqlinstance -U sa  -P pass -d master -A I'm getting the following error :

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 43 - An error occurred while obtaining the dedicated administrator connection (DAC) port. Make sure that SQL Browser is running, or check the error log for the port number) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)*

I can connect using DAC but only as admin:hostmachine or sqlcmd -S hostmachine -U sa  -P pass -d master -A

Comment: I have added an inbound rule for port UDP 1434 on firewall. SQL Browser is running.

Comment: I have added on SQL server instance , at startup parameters -T7806 and now it works.